# Common refinement of partitions is finite

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof, set-partition

I'm working on proving the following:

Lemma: Let $I$ be a bounded interval, and let **P** and **P'** be two partitions of $I$. Then the common refinement of **P** and **P'**, **P#P'** is also a partition of I, and is both finer than **P** and finer than **P'**.

where a partition **P** of a bounded set $I$ is defined as a finite set of bounded intervals contained in $I$ such that $x\in I \Rightarrow \exists ! J\in\ $**P** such that $x\in J$; **P'** is finer that **P** if $\forall J\in\ $**P'** $\exists K\in $**P** such that $J\subseteq K$ and finally **P#P'**$:=\{K\cap J:K\in$**P** and $J\in $ **P'**$\}$.

Now, I've proved that:

(1) every element in **P#P'** is a bounded interval contained in $I$;

(2) $x\in I \Rightarrow \exists ! H\in\ $**P#P'** such that $x\in H$;

(3) **P#P'** is finer than both **P** and **P'**;

the only thing that is left is to show that **P#P'** is finite.

To do this I thought about  showing that the cardinality of **P#P'** $\leq$ cardinality of **P** $\times$ cardinality of **P'** by first finding a bijection between each $K\cap J \in $**P#P'** and each ordered pair $(K,J)\in $**P**$\times$**P'**. But this approach seems too intricate to me to prove such a result so I'd like to know if anyone knows of a simpler way to prove this.

---

EDIT: Do you think the following proof is rigorous enough?

Let $M$ be the cardinality of **P** and $N$ the cardinality of **P'**; then, since for each $K\in $**P** there are at most $N$ intervals $J\in $**P'** such that $K\cap J\in $**P#P'** we have that for each $K\in $**P** there are at most $N$ elements in **P#P'**. Now, since the elements $K\in $**P** are themselves at most $M$ it follows that **P#P'** has at most $M\cdot N$ elements and is thus finite.

Comment: The (evident) surjectivity of $\langle K,J\rangle\mapsto K\cap J$ is enough.

Comment: @drhab : sure, how silly of me, I overlooked that. Thank you very much. If you'll write your comment  as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\boldsymbol{P}\times\boldsymbol{P'}\to\boldsymbol{P}$#$\boldsymbol{P'}$ prescribed by$\langle K,J\rangle\mapsto K\cap J$ is evidently surjective.

This allows us to conclude that the cardinality of $\boldsymbol{P}$#$\boldsymbol{P'}$ will not exceed the cardinality of $\boldsymbol{P}\times\boldsymbol{P'}$, hence will be finite.